# How to sort simplexml returned from API call

Tags: php, sorting, simplexml

I need to sort this multidimensional array, and nothing that I've found on this site or through my friend Google has lead me to the correct solution.

```
$url = file_get_contents('http://api.petfinder.com/shelter.getPets?key=&id=&status=A&output=full&count=999');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($url); 
// this is the returned array (see below for example)

foreach($xml->pets->pet as $pet) { 
// ->pet, or $pet is what needs to be sorted
    $data['id'] = (string)$pet->id;
}
```

Here is the example of the array that is returned by the API call above...

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[header] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [status] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [code] => 100
            )
    )
[lastOffset] => 82
[pets] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [pet] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [id] => 10595710
                        [name] => Lizzie
                        [animal] => Dog
                        [options] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [option] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => altered
                                        [1] => hasShots
                                        [2] => housebroken
                                    )
                            )
                        [lastUpdate] => 2012-10-11T15:19:05Z
                        [media] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [photos] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [photo] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/US/NC/NC416/10595710/NC416.10595710-1-x.jpg
                                                [1] => http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/US/NC/NC416/10595710/NC416.10595710-1-fpm.jpg
                                            )
                                    )
                            )
                        [contact] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [email] => jghfjhgf
                            )
                    )
                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [id] => 11036032
                        [name] => Buddy
                        [animal] => Dog
                        [breeds] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [breed] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Terrier
                                        [1] => Black Labrador Retriever
                                    )

                            )
                        [options] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [option] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => altered
                                        [1] => hasShots
                                        [2] => housebroken
                                    )
                            )
                        [lastUpdate] => 2012-10-11T15:19:05Z
                        [media] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [photos] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [photo] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/US/NC/NC416/11036032/NC416.11036032-1-x.jpg
                                                [1] => http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/US/NC/NC416/11036032/NC416.11036032-1-fpm.jpg
                                            )
                                    )
                            )
                        [contact] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [email] => kfkhgkhjg
                            )
                    )
                [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ...
```

I need to be able to sort  alphabetically by pets' names OR by the 'lastUpdate' entry. These will be separate sorting methods.

Comment: This is not a multidimensional array but an object of type `SimpleXMLElement`. BTW, this topic is covered more often I suggest you start with some existing material. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How+to+sort+simplexml

Comment: @hakre `$xml->pets->pet` is an array indeed.

Comment: I think you would need to use `usort` which allows you to pass in a comparator.  See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: @bažmegakapa: No, you can not trust `var_dump`/`print_r` here because it is a `SimpleXMLElement` for real, but displayed as an array. See http://eval.in/12072